# Suppose that an entire function $f$ is holomorphic at infinity. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

We say that that a function $f$ is meromorphic at infinity if the function $g(z) = f(1/z)$ has a pole at $0$.

Suppose that an entire function $f$ is holomorphic at infinity.
Show that $f$ is constant.

My attempt:

$f(1/z) = z^{-n}×h(z)$ and so $f'(1/z) = -nz^{-n-1}×h(z) + z^{-n}×h'(z)$, and so we can write $f'(1/z) = \frac{-n}{z^{n+1}}×h(z) + \frac{h'(z)}{z^n}$, and so taking the limit as $n \to$ infinity, we get $f'(1/z) = 0$ so $f$ is constant

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: If $f$ is *holomorphic* at infinity then $f(\frac1z)$ is holomorphic at zero, it does not have a pole, i.e. $n=0$. You are instead trying to prove that an entire function meromorphic at infinity is constant, which is wrong, as you can see considering every non-constant polynomial.

Comment: @Caffeine I don't know why my answer is wrong. Can you please show me how it's done?

Comment: And I edited it. It's now "Suppose that an entire function $f$ is meromorphic at infinity"

Comment: You have $f(1/z) = z^{-n}×h(z)$ for some (fixed) $n$ and $h$. You cannot take the limit for $n$ to infinity. – And the statement is wrong: Every *polynomial* is an entire function and meromorphic at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

An entire function meromorphic at infinity is not necessarily constant: as an example, take a non-constant polinomial $P(z)$.

Your attempt is flawed because

$$f'\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{h'(z)z-nh(z)}{z^{n+1}}$$

does not imply that $f'(1/z)\to 0$, as$h(z)$ may grow faster then $z^n$ (take $f(z)=z$ to see it explicitly).

It is true, however, that every entire function holomorphic infinity is constant. To prove this, note that $f(1/z)$ is bounded in the unit disc and thus $f(z)$ is bounded for all $|z|>1$. By Liouville's theorem, $f$ is constant.

As a final note, there is a possible characterization of entire functions meromorphic at infinity: they are exactly the polynomials.

Comment: Yes I fixed the question: "Suppose that an entire function $f$ is holomorphic at infinity. Show that $f$ is constant." could ypu please explain further why is this true?

Comment: I mean $|f(1/z)| = \frac{1}{|z|^n} × |h(z)|$, so if $z \in$ unit disc, doesn't that mean that $|z| < 1$? And so we will have $|f(1/z)| > |h(z)|$ in the unit disc? How is $f$ then bounded?

Comment: @JOJO: Since the function is *holomorphic* at infinity there's no $\frac{1}{z^n}$ factor. Since $f(1/z)$ is holomorphic in the unit disc, it is bounded for $\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1$, i.e. for $|z|>1$

Comment: You mean there's no $h(z)$, so $f(1/z) = 1/z^n$?

Comment: @JOJO the exact opposite, there's no $1/z^n$

Comment: Okay but then how does holomorphicity of $f(1/z)$ in the unit disc tell me that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @JOJO if $f\left(\frac1z\right)$ is holomorphic, it is continuous. Since the closed unit disc is compact, the function must have a point of maximum modulus (let us call it M), and thus is bounded. Since $\forall \left|\frac1z\right|\le 1 \left |f\left(\frac1z\right)\right|\le M$ we have that $\forall |z|>1 |f(z)|\le M$