# Proving holomorphic functions on C and infinity are constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to prove that the only holomorphic functions on $S=\mathbf{C}\cup \infty$ are constant.

**My Proof:**

Suppose $f$ is such function. Then we can write
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n.$$

Define $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ for every complex number but zero.. So
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{-n}.$$

Since $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$ it follows that $f$ converges to a limit at $\infty$. More presicesly, we require the existance of a constant $M$ such that
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)=M.$$

So
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} g(z)=\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)=M$$ which implies that g is bounded and hence $0$ is a removable singularity. Therefore, $a_1,a_2,...=0$ and hence
$$g(z)=M \implies f(z)=M$$
which proves that $f$ is constant.

**My issues with this proof:** My biggest issue is that I am not sure if the argument "holomorphic at infinity implies $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)=M$ from all directions" is true. Moreover the argument "0 is removable singularity $g$ therefore $a_1,a_2,\cdot = 0$. If anybody could check if this correct I would greatly appreciate it.

**Further thoughts:** One idea that I had was to use Louiseville's Theorem. I was thinking of something of the lines of using the assertion in the above-attempted proof that $f$ being holomorphic at infinity implies $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z)=M$. And hence the exitance of a closed disc of some radius centered at the origin such that all points on its boundary and not on the disc get mapped to epsilon less than $M$. Using compact sets, the maximum of $f$ on that disc must occur on the boundary, however, by construction, the boundary points will be epsilon less than $M$ and therefore $f$ is bounded by $M$ and is therefore constant.

However, the same issues arise as I am not certain about the holomorphism $\implies$ limit assertion.

If anybody check the above arguments and give me some feedback/thoughts I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3652062/42969

Comment: You may have a typo. The correct spelling is Liousville, not Louiseville.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Actually it is Liouville.

Comment: There's a simple topological argument: $S$ is compact, and continuous functions (which holomorphic functions are) preserve compactness. So the image of such a function is a compact subset of $\mathbb C$, and thus bounded. Now apply Liouville to a suitable restriction of the function.

Comment: @MartinR . Thank u....................

Answer (score 0):

Holomorphic at $\infty$ does imply the existence of $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ or $\lim_{z \to 0}f(\frac 1 z)$. This implies that $f$ is bounded in $\{z:|z| >1\}$ because $f(\frac 1z)$ is bounded in $\{z: |z| <1\}$. Since any continuous function is bounded on the closed unit disk (by compactness of the disk) it folows that $f$ is bounded and Liouville's Theorem shows that $f$ is a constant.
The arguemnert that $a_1=a_2=...=0$ because $f(\frac 1 z)$ has  removable singularity at $0$  does not make sense.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have a question about in regards to $a_1=a_2=\dots=0$ not implying $f(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at 0. When I was first thinking about it, I thought it was correct because removable singularity lets us know that the limit at that value is well defined and therefore it can not be a pole or a essential singularity. Therefore we can not have any negative order terms in the Laurent series.  The above is probably wrong as you have mentioned however I can't see why. Could you help me understand why such argument does not hold?

Comment: @MathsWizzard How do you conclude that $a_1=a_2=..=0$ from the fact that $0$ is a removable singulairity? Which theorem are you using?

Comment: I am not using a theorem per say. My logic is that a singularity can not be both (or all 3) of any of  aremovable singularity, pole, and essential singularity. Knowing it is removable eliminates the other two posibilities. By definition of what it means to be a pole and an essential singularity we conclude (for $z=0$ to not be either of them) that all of the negative order terms of the laurent series must be zero. At least this is how I think about it. I could be wrong. Any thoughts on where is the error in this logic (if there is one) ?